# C# Task Synchronization methods

Tags: c#, multithreading, xamarin, synchronization, task

i have the PostRequestAsync method that process all the back-end calls.
I do the Menu and Login call, and after that, all the other calls can be done, but not previously because the execution is not safe.
Here there's the example of how i make a menu call, and it's similar for all the call.
I don't think that using deadlocks is the right way in c#. Could someone suggest me the proper way to handle this situation?

The actual code is:

```
public async Task<T> PostRequestAsync<T>(){
if (servicePath.Contains("menu")) IsLoginFinished = false;
if(!(servicePath.Contains("menu") || servicePath.Contains("login")))
 while (IsLoginFinished == false) ;
--
--- Other Code
--
if (servicePath.Contains("login")) IsLoginFinished = true; }
```

Here there's the call to the PostRequestAsync

```
public async Task<ResponseCallModel> Menu(){
return await PHttpClient.Instance.PostRequestAsync<ResponseMenuRecuperaModel>(); }
```

And the call to Menu

```
var retrieve = await service.Menu();
```

Comment: I don't think that any "uses" deadhlock. A deadlock would be an unwanted behaviour.

Comment: @osh arko Try looking for https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Can you include the async call in the code?

Comment: @PeterBons i added the code.

netaholic i'm not sure that this would be the right function. now i added the various call, do you think that it's right?

Comment: Your code sample would not compile.  The function `PostRequestAsync` has to return an instance of T which I don't see after the last if statement unless you're returning an object in the portion of 'Other Code' which would make every line of code after that irrelevant.  As well the calling code in `Menu()` - you cannot call `PostRequestAsync` as the function is non-static.

Comment: the program works. I forgot to write the return into the PostRequestAsync method, but everything compile and works. my need is another.